# How to pass an environmental variable in kubeflow pipeline?

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I want the variable to be accessed by `gcr.io/******/serve_model:lat5` Image which is an argument of `gcr.io/******/deployservice:lat2`

Initially I have tried passing the variable as argument but it didn't work, so I am trying to pass it as an environmental variable.
My environmental variable will be an url of `GCP` storage bucket from where my `serve_model` will access the `.sav` model file.

```
        name='web-ui',
        image='gcr.io/******/deployservice:lat2',
        arguments=[
        '--image', 'gcr.io/******/serve_model:lat5',
        '--name', 'web-ui',
        '--container-port', '8080',
        '--service-port', '80',
        '--service-type', "LoadBalancer"
        ]
        ).add_env_variable(V1EnvVar(name='modelurl', value=Model_Path))
```

Comment: Do you want to pass only one value? Did you considered `ConfigMap` to do it? https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/

Comment: Yes I want to pass only one value.. an url to load my model

Comment: @PjoterS
I pass my environmental variable in my pipeline python file as :
```web_ui.container.add_env_variable(V1EnvVar(name='modelurl', value=Model_Path))```

And have put the below in my .sh file to run in kubeflow(kubernetes):

```kubectl create configmap modelurl --from-literal=modelurl=Model_Path```

Is it a right way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as Community Wiki for better visibility as Original Poster was able to pass this variable.

It's the best `Kubernetes` way to pass value.

> [ConfigMap](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/ultimate-configmap-guide-kubernetes.html) is a dictionary of configuration settings. This
>   dictionary consists of key-value pairs of strings. Kubernetes provides
>   these values to your containers. ConfigMap stores configuration
>   settings for your code. Store connection strings, public credentials,
>   hostnames, and URLs in your ConfigMap.

You can create `ConfigMap` in many ways (from file, manually, etc). More information can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-a-configmap).

**Solution**

According to Original Poster comment:

**1.** Pass environmental variable using pipeline python file and `container` function `add_env_variable`:

`web_ui.container.add_env_variable(V1EnvVar(name='modelurl', value=Model_Path))`

**2.** Prepare command which will create config map with proper value:

`kubectl create configmap modelurl --from-literal=modelurl=Model_Path`

**3.** Put previous command to script which will be used in `Kubeflow`.

Answer (score 2):

`add_env_variable()` is a function of a `Container` object that's exposed as a property of a `ContainerOp`.

So something like below would work. Refer the kfp dsl code [here](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/sdk/python/kfp/dsl/_container_op.py#L121)

```
model_path = 'gcp://dummy-url'
container_op = ContainerOp(name='web-ui',
                               image='gcr.io/******/deployservice:lat2',
                               arguments=[
                                   '--image', 'gcr.io/******/serve_model:lat5',
                                   '--name', 'web-ui',
                                   '--container-port', '8080',
                                   '--service-port', '80',
                                   '--service-type', "LoadBalancer"]
                               )
container_op.container.add_env_variable(V1EnvVar(name='model_url', value=model_path))
```

You can verify this by checking the YAML in the zip for the `env` section under `-container`

```
  - container:
      args:
      - --image
      - gcr.io/******/serve_model:lat5
      - --name
      - web-ui
      - --container-port
      - '8080'
      - --service-port
      - '80'
      - --service-type
      - LoadBalancer
      env:
      - name: modelurl
        value: gcp://dummy-url <--the static env value
      image: gcr.io/******/deployservice:lat2
```

Comment: It seems that already used this but didn't paste whole code in question.

Comment: The code that's posted in the question is running `add_env_variable()` right after the `)` which makes it seem like you're running it on the `ContainerOp` object, and *not* the `Container` object nested inside. Running the above code should get you the URL in the env (check the yaml snippet above). If your yaml shows like that, the env var should be accessible in the pipeline. 
My point being, if the URL path is a static string, you do not need a ConfigMap for it.